# How to include column not included in Group By

Tags: sql, ssms

I have the table DirectCosts with the following columns:

- DetailsID (unique)
- InvoiceNumber
- ProjectID
- PayableID

I need to find the duplicates combinations of payableid and invoicenumber.

How can I adjust the following query so that it accommodates the combination AND displays the list of instead of the count?

```sql
SELECT sinvoicenumber, count(*)
FROM exportdirectcostdetails where iprocoreprojectid = 1187294
GROUP BY sinvoicenumber
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Is there a way it can display all columns?

Comment: @KenWhite Using SSMS. I have corrected the tags. Thanks

Comment: SQL Server requires that all non-aggregated columns from yoru SELECT be in the GROUP BY expression.

Comment: `No column name was specified for column 2 of 'ed2'`. => You need to give an alias to the inner query `count(sinvoicenumber)`

Answer (score 0):

**Original Question** : Why do I get error ed2 should have column name defined

You are having a derived table, so you need to have column names for the derived table.

```sql
select ed1.sinvoicenumber, 
       ed1.ipayableid, 
       ed2.sinvoicenumber 
from   ExportDirectCostDetails ed1
inner join 
(
       SELECT sinvoicenumber, count(sinvoicenumber) AS InvoiceNumberCount
       FROM   exportdirectcostdetails 
       where  iprocoreprojectid = 1187294
       GROUP BY sinvoicenumber
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
) ed2 
on ed1.sinvoicenumber = ed2.sinvoicenumber
```

**Updated Question:** How to have all column names

You need to have PARTITION BY clause defined and then apply filter as given below:

```sql
SELECT t.* FROM
(SELECT *, count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY payableid,invoiceNumber) AS InvoiceCount
FROM exportdirectcostdetails where iprocoreprojectid = 1187294) as t
WHERE InvoiceCount > 1
```

Comment: I have just updated the question, but this is helpful for my previous query I was working with. Is there a way I can display the duplicates only?

Comment: @wemice, changing question will lead to confusion for new visitors to the site and makes the answer not related. I am updating my answer.